# TCL hang on gets

Tags: c, tcl, io-redirection

I have a parent C process that creates a child tcl process and re-directs the stdin/stdout of the child to interact with the parent.  It seems to work correctly but there is a part where the child never receives what the parent is receiving.  If any one can spot the error that causes this I would appreciate it.

Parent sending code:

```
fprintf(write_to, "%s",outmsg.data); //Received by child
bzero ((char *) &inmsg, sizeof (inmsg));
getmsg (sock, &inmsg);
if (ntohl (inmsg.type) != MATCH)
  protocol_error (MATCH, &inmsg);
strncpy (opphandle, inmsg.data, maxSize);
opphandle[maxSize] = '\0';
fprintf (write_to,"%s",opphandle); //Received by child
fprintf (write_to,"%s",inmsg.board); //Not Received by child
```

both board and data fields in inmsg are of type char[].

Child recieving code:

```
set handle [gets stdin] //Received
set ohandle [gets stdin]//Received
set myShape [gets stdin]//Not received
```

Note, when the parent is killed with ctrl+C the child thinks it received input for myShap and then executes with myShape being ctrl+C.

Again, stdin and stdout of the child have been redirected so that stdin comes from the parent and stdout goes to the parent.

Comment: `gets` waits for newline. It's probable that both `outmsg.data` and `opphandle` ends in newlines (`"\n"` or `"\r"` or `"\r\n"`). Are you sure your shape file end in a newline?

Comment: @slebetman thank you! That fixed it right up, I thought it was looking for '\0' I'm new at tcl and all of the resources seem to be very difficult to find and are very confusing.

Comment: Tcl is designed to be very easy to find documentation for... if you live in the 80s :) The documentation is complete but unlike more modern projects such as jQuery or .NET, the documentation has much less "bling". All of tcl are documented in man pages so doing `man gets` would have solved this. Unfortunately, the documentation itself is written a lot like man pages: short and terse. Almost every word has meaning so you must read the docs carefully.

Comment: In this case, the solution appears in the first line of the docs for `gets`. It says: `gets - Read a line from a channel`. Assuming you are aware of the traditional unix definition of a "line" (and tcl's definition of line endings) it should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: For full documentation of tcl commands I usually go to: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6 -- replace 8.6 for the version you're interested in and click on the "Tcl Commands" link.

Comment: Make sure the side writing to the pipe is flushing as well; by default, most programs (including Tcl and anything using C stdio) switch to _full_ buffering when not writing to a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gets` command waits for newline.

It's probable that both outmsg.data and opphandle ends in newlines (`"\n"` or `"\r"` or `"\r\n"`). It would explain why the first two `gets` works.

Check to see if `inmsg.board` ends in a newline. If not, you can simply do:

```
fprintf (write_to,"%s\n",inmsg.board);
```

---

For robustness, it's better to strip strings of trailing newlines before sending. Then add the newline again in the `fprintf()` like the example above. This is to avoid cases where extra newlines accidentally causing your tcl script to read an empty line as data.

An alternative is to implement a proper scanner/parser in the tcl script to ignore empty lines.